# Считывание символов с клавиатуры

Tags: c, файлы

Может кто-нибудь сможет подсказать, почему в функции:

```
char funkcKlawiatura (char *TXT)
{
    printf("Wprowadz tekst z klawiatury: ");
    fgets(TXT, sizeof(TXT), stdin);
    printf ("%s", TXT);
    
    return *TXT;
}
```

Только три символа сохраняются в массиве?

Полный код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char funkcPlik (char *TXT)
{
    FILE *file;
        printf("Podaj adres pliku: ");
        char adres[256];
        if (fgets(adres, 256, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf("Ma miejsce blad lub został przeczytany EOF");
    }
    else
        {
        /* Usuwamy symbol końca wierza */
        int last = strlen(adres) - 1;

        if (adres[last] == '\n')
            adres[last] = '\0';

        /* Tutaj można przeanalizować wiersz */

        }
    printf("\n");
    if ((file = fopen(adres, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Nie udalo sie otworzyc pliku, uruchom ponownie! \n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
        {
        while(feof (file) == 0) {
            if (fread(TXT, sizeof(char), sizeof(TXT), file) != 0)
                printf("%s", TXT);
        }
        fclose(file);
        }
        return *TXT;
}

char funkcKlawiatura (char *TXT)
{
    printf("Wprowadz tekst z klawiatury: ");
    fgets(TXT, sizeof(TXT), stdin);
    printf ("%s", TXT);
    
    return *TXT;
}

int funkcFind ()
{
    return 0;
}

int main ()
{   
    char * TXT = (char*)calloc(10240,sizeof(char));
    printf("Tekst bedzie wprowadzony z pliku 'p', czy z klawiatury 'k': ");
    char c;
    c = getchar ();
    while (getchar () != '\n') continue;
    switch (c)
    {
    case 'p':
        
        funkcPlik (TXT);
        
    break;
    
    case 'k':
    
        funkcKlawiatura (TXT);
        
    break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char funkcKlawiatura (char *TXT)
{
    printf("Wprowadz tekst z klawiatury: ");
    fgets(TXT, sizeof(TXT), stdin);
```

`char * TXT` - т.е. тип `TXT` - указатель. Значит, `sizeof(TXT)` - **размер указателя**. 4 байта в 32-разрядном приложении, 8 - в 64-разрядном...

Comment: Спасибо. А как это исправить? Почему не перезаписывает тогда указатель, а только пишет под адрес указателя? т.е. `fgets(TXT, sizeof(TXT), stdin);` пишет нормально под адрес указателя TXT, а не перезаписывает его, в то время как sizeof(TXT) определяет размер указателя.

Comment: Потому что первым параметром в функцию передается адрес того места в памяти, куда писать - тот, который и хранится в `TXT`. Для перезаписи самой переменной надо `fgets(&TXT,...` Исправить? передавать размер выделенной памяти отдельным параметром - 10240.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.